# Tag images are hard-coded to use http

Tags: bug, status-planned, ssl

## Steps to reproduce

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox (note the `s` in `https`)
2. View source (`view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox`, doesn't get converted to a link, sadly)
3. Search for `src="http:`

### Expected result

All images sources should begin with `https://` or `//` when accessing the site via HTTPS.

### Actual result

Tag images specify `http` (although `https` works fine):

```html
<a href="/questions/tagged/firefox" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;firefox&#39;" rel="tag"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcBXc.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">firefox</a>
```

Some gravatar images specify `http` (although `https` works fine). I believe only those attached to "ignored tags":

```html
<a href="/users/1684778/sundara"><div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SAzi.jpg?s=32&g=1" alt=""></div></a>
```

---

**Note:** I know HTTPS isn't officially supported yet, but one less thing to worry about down the road, eh?

Comment: Related MSE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221304/make-all-i-stack-imgur-com-links-protocol-relative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>I've updated the codebase so that new sponsored tags, going forward will use protocol relative URIs.</strike>

Once that's been pushed out, I'll update the currently stored URIs to be protocol relative as well.

One small step for sponsored tags, a tiny leap for HTTPS support.

---

The above has been backed out - there were a few bad assumptions in the fix and some paths were missed.

When we get closer to getting HTTPS working everywhere, we will revisit a proper fix for this.

Comment: Any progress on this? I think that should be really easy to fix.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, what did the fix break? The [client-side fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231416) I wrote for this issue in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) seems to be working fine for me, but if there are any surprising corner cases, I'd like to know about them.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - mostly on the admin side of things, so... probably nothing for you to worry about.